# Align multiline

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I use bootstrap 5

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
    <h5 class="text-light mb-4">Stay in contact</h5>
    <p><i class="fa fa-map-marker-alt me-3"></i>619 Otaroad-north-Sidrac, New York, New York 291290 </p>
    <p><i class="fa fa-phone-alt me-3"></i><a href="tel:213-622-1212">213-622-1212</a></p>
    <p><i class="fa fa-envelope me-3"></i><a href="mailto:bob@bob.usa">bob@bob.usa</a></p>
</div>
```

How to align text on multiline?

Is there a way to align New York with 619?

I tried to replace p tag with span and add style: word-wrap: break-word;

with no succes

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible: simply apply `display: flex;` to the first `p` element, which will treat the icon and the subsequent text as two flex items. (You might want to assign a class to the `p` element to be able to address it more independently):

```css
p:first-of-type {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6" style="width: 200px;">
    <h5 class="text-light mb-4">Stay in contact</h5>
    <p><i class="fa fa-map-marker-alt me-3">X&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>619 Otaroad-north-Sidrac, New York, New York 291290 </p>
    <p><i class="fa fa-phone-alt me-3">X&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</i><a href="tel:213-622-1212">213-622-1212</a></p>
    <p><i class="fa fa-envelope me-3">X&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</i><a href="mailto:bob@bob.usa">bob@bob.usa</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but that is a pretty ugly solution. In the case the icons have different widths it would mess the whole thing up. You would have to adjust the html with 1 space here, 3 spaces there... Like I said, really ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much cleaner solution. There is no need to add `&nbsp;`

```css
p {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20px auto;
  gap: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6" style="width: 200px;">
    <h5 class="text-light mb-4">Stay in contact</h5>
    <p><i class="fa fa-map-marker-alt me-3">XX</i>619 Otaroad-north-Sidrac, New York, New York 291290 </p>
    <p><i class="fa fa-phone-alt me-3">X</i><a href="tel:213-622-1212">213-622-1212</a></p>
    <p><i class="fa fa-envelope me-3">X</i><a href="mailto:bob@bob.usa">bob@bob.usa</a></p>
</div>
```